# How to light up picamera LED without taking photo

Tags: python, raspicam, picamera

I want to light up the picamera LED using python for a few seconds as a test to see if it works, **without actually taking a photo**. *And yes I know I can test that by just taking a photo and watching it light up*

I've read through the picamera documentation and can't seem to find a command to do it, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn on the camera led through the pi’s GPIO using the python code below:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
 import time
 import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

 # Use GPIO numbering
 GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    
 # Set GPIO for camera LED
 # Use 5 for Model A/B and 32 for Model B+
 CAMLED = 5 
 
 # Set GPIO to output
 GPIO.setup(CAMLED, GPIO.OUT, initial=False)

 GPIO.output(CAMLED,True) # On
 time.sleep(1)
 GPIO.output(CAMLED,False) # Off
```

But I believe that this may require you to first disable the red led by adding the following line:

```
disable_camera_led=1
```

To your config file which can be opened with the following command:

```
sudo nano /boot/config.txt
```

Comment: Of course this will only work with Picamera V1. Picamera V2 does not have a LED.

Answer (score 0):

On a Pi Zero the GPIO pin is 40:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
CAMLED = 40
GPIO.setup(CAMLED, GPIO.OUT, initial=False)
GPIO.output(CAMLED,True)
time.sleep(1)
GPIO.output(CAMLED,False)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).